# Wrapping internet address length in the references

Tags: bibliographies, urls

A URL in the referencs exceeds the column width and I want to know how to wrap that?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\title{my title} 
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Paper~\cite{Nsight18} shows

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{Nsight18} NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition, https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/achievedflops.htm [online], 2018.
\end{thebibliography}
\vspace{12pt}
\end{document}
```

See the output

[image]

Comment: Load the `xurl` package and encase the URL string in a `\url{..}` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your TeX distribution features the `xurl` package, you should use it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{xurl}
\title{my title} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section 1}
Paper~\cite{Nsight18} shows \dots

\begin{thebibliography}{00}

\bibitem{Nsight18} NVIDIA Nsight Visual Studio Edition, 
\url{https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/achievedflops.htm} 
[online], 2018.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```